# Create two route options to the same page (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I want to be able to access the same page in two different ways:

First, with a parameter, to show some specific information.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "About",
            "About/{id}",
            new { controller = "About", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Second, without parameter, to show general things.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "About",
            "About",
            new { controller = "About", action = "Index" }
        );
```

How can I build the route to accept both options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "About",
    "About/{id}",
    new { controller = "About", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    // if id = null => /About was requested
    // if id != null => /About/abc was requested
    ...
}
```